# Knapsack or bin packing problem?

Tags: combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, np-complete

I have $i$ items and I should pre-packed $m$ knapsacks with identical items where only $K<n$ items can be packed. Also, we should have only one of each item in each sack. The time capacity for knapsacks preparation is limited to $C_{m}$ for each sack. The $t_{i}$ is the packaging time of item $i$. The objective is to minimize the packaging costs. 
I believe it is a multiply constrained knapsack problem and it is also bounded. However, It has some similarities and differences with bin packing problem as well.
I am wondering if this problem is a variant of knapsack problem. Is it still NP-hard? If so, how can I prove it? Thanks.

The formulation is:

$$\min \sum_{i \in I}c_{i}z_{i}x_{m} $$
$$\sum_{i \in I}z_{i} \le K  $$ 
$$\sum_{i \in I} t_{i} x_{m} \le C_{m} \hspace{0.35in}\forall m \in M   $$
$$x_{m} \le u \hspace{0.35in}\forall m \in M $$ 
$$x_{m} \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \hspace{0.35in}\forall m \in M $$
$$z_{i} \in \{0,1\} \hspace{0.35in}\forall i \in I $$

Comment: Sorry, not super clear what you're trying to model. The math is clear, but I can't understand the narrative.

Comment: @Bey thank you! Does the model is a knapsack problem? if so, what type of knapsack is it?

Comment: You haven't specified what $t_i$ is

Comment: @ Bey, the $t_{i}$ is the packaging time of item $i$.

Comment: Your objective function looks off: why doesn't it run over all $m\in M$ too? Also, what is $u$. I think $x$ should be doubly indexed, correct? $x_{m,i}$ and you need a constraint like $x_{m,i} \leq z_i Q$ where $Q$ is some large positive integer (basically, big-M constraint).